# How to delete a head?

Tags: mercurial

I have pushed some files by mistake and it shows different heads in main repository. How can I delete that head?

Comment: If you really don't want a local branch you have the option to delete and clone again, see #3 here https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/PruningDeadBranches

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you actually want to delete the heads.  If you do that, you will lose the work that was done in those branches.

You probably want to merge the heads back into one branch.

Say that you have a tree like this:

```
o  4 : Head 1
|
o  3 : Another commit
|  
| o 2 : Head 2
| |
|/
o  1 : A commit
|
o  0 : Initial commit
```

To get rid of the additional head without losing the work contained within it you would merge the two heads (revisions 2 and 4 in this example) like this:

```
hg update 4
hg merge 2
hg commit -m "Merge"
```

That will create another commit which has all the changes in revisions 2, 3 and 4 in a single head like this:

```
o     5: Merge
|\
o |   4 : Head 1
| |
o |   3 : Another commit
| | 
| o   2 : Head 2
| |
|/
o     1 : A commit
|
o     0 : Initial commit
```

This is standard procedure when multiple developers work on the same repository.

Comment: I tried to merge, when im merging, there are 3 deferent source are in other 3 heads. so its very deficult to merge. other important thing is, when I `push`(I think without run the `pull` command) created a new head.so if I have local changes(backup), Can I remove new head withouth damaging other heads?

Comment: You can't remove commits that have been pushed already.  Also,  you shouldn't create a new head by pushing  your changes.  The push should fail if it would create a new head.  Are you forcing the push with `hg push -f`?  You shouldn't do that because it fails precisely to prevent this issue.

Comment: Also,  you don't merge four heads,  you merge two heads repeatedly until there is only one left.  The merge conflicts need to be dealt with and you should  pull/merge/push frequently to make them easier.

Comment: yes, I used `hg push -f` command.I fixed it successfully. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 12):

You can enable the "mq" extension by editing your `.hgrc` file.
Make sure the following lines are present:

```
[extensions]
mq =
```

Afterwards you can "strip" a specific revision which deletes it so that you have only one head:

```
hg strip ...
```

Comment: After check in 4 ppl, 4 heads created, so, can I delete 1 by 1 head using header id

Comment: Yes, you can specify the revision number you want to delete using `-r` parameter.

Comment: @Robert: He says he's pushed. Stripping public change-sets isn't going to help.

Comment: thank you @Robert for your answer.that was really helpful to find the solution.